# Query Bindings codeigniter insert into array?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, binding, insert

Is it possible to make the following code?

```
   $sql = "insert into table (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) vaues(?)"; 
   $data = array ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g');
   $this->db->query($sql,$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insert_batch` to insert rows from array.

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'a' => 'a' ,
      'b' => 'b' ,
      'c' => 'c' ,
      'd' => 'd' ,
      'e' => 'e' ,
      'f' => 'f' ,
      'g' => 'g'
   ),
   array(
      'a' => 'h' ,
      'b' => 'i' ,
      'c' => 'j' ,
      'd' => 'k' ,
      'e' => 'l' ,
      'f' => 'm' ,
      'g' => 'n'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
```

You have to rebuild the array to use it.

Details : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch